# Enviar datos por post y redireccionar a la página que los recibe con javascript ó jquery ó ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Como puedo abrir la página a la que le pase parámetros por post usando javascript o jquery.

Página index.php:

En ella tengo imágenes y cada una tiene su id, cuando doy click en una imagen tomo su id y lo guardo en un array. Posteriormente tengo que enviar ese array por post a la página prueba_numeros.php la cual tengo que abrirla y mostrar el array que está recibiendo.

JavaScript:

```
<script>
var numeros = [];

function agregar(e)
{
 numeros.push(e.id);
}

function siguiente()
{
  var xhttp;

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
     xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  else
     xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
    {
        window.open("prueba_numeros.php");
    }
  } 

  xhttp.open("POST", "prueba_numeros.php");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("numeros=" + JSON.stringify(numeros));
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <img id="1" src="img/1.png" onClick="agregar(this);">
 </td>
   .
   .
 </tr>
   .
   .
</table>

<input type="button" value="Siguiente" onClick="siguiente();">
```

Página prueba_numeros.php:

En esta página tengo que mostrar el array que recibe de la página index.php por medio de post:

**Números seleccionados:** 1, 2, 3, etc.

Como pueden ver estoy usando puro javascript pero si tienen alguna solución usando jquery ó ajax también será bien recibida.

Answer (score 0):

Modifico completamente la respuesta para ajustar a lo que necesitas

Debes modificar de esta forma tu html, agregando un formulario y colocando un botón para realizar un submit, dentro del form hay un campo oculto que guardara los números que seleccionaste:

```
<form action="prueba_numeros.php" methood="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdnNumeros" id="hdnNumeros">
    <input type="submit" value="Siguiente">
</form>
```

y debes modificar tu función agregar para concatenar los números seleccionados y asignarlos al campo hdnNumeros oculto, ahora estarás enviado los datos por post a tu otra página

```
function agregar(e){
    numeros.push(e.id);
    $('#hdnNumeros').val( numeros.join(',') )
}
```

Luego en tu pagina `prueba_numeros.php` sólo debes hacer un echo de la variable `$_POST['hdnNumeros']`

Comment: De acuerdo pero como haria para abrir la página prueba_numeros.php que es a la que estoy enviando el array?? O sea una vez que ya se haya enviado el array se tiene que cerrar la página index y se tiene que abrir la página prueba_numeros mostrando el array que recibió.

Comment: Re hice mi respuesta. Saludos!

Comment: Es de afuerza que tengo que usar un formulario, si no quisiera hacerlo así no se podría??

Comment: Para enviarlos por post a otra pagina que abres con javascript, no... por eso en mi respuesta anterior te indicaba que podías enviarlos a otra pagina pero para procesarlos, considerando que no estas conectado a ninguna base de datos donde eventualmente podrías hacer algo como enviarlos por ajax para procesarlos y una vez procesados redireccionas a otra pagina para ver tus datos procesados pero ya desde una base de datos

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no tiene sentido enviar una consulta asincrona que luego vas a ver de forma sincrona.
Las tecnologias asincronas, sobre todo en desarrollo web estan orientadas a enviar y recibir datos sin la necesidad de cargar otra pagina o la misma.

Lo que si puedes hacer es enviar una consulta asincrona desde index.php e indicarle al servidor que genere una respuesta. Esa respuesta generada por el servidor la vas a enviar a la misma pagina que el navegador tiene abierta, o sea index.php que es donde se genero la consulta asincrona.

Por ejemplo:
prueba_numeros.php

```
//Esperando la solicitud del cliente
if(isset($_POST["id_arr"]))
{
     // Iteras sobre el array de IDs y lo concatenas 
     // si quieres para hacer una salida unica
     // luego has un echo a la variable con el arreglo concatenado
     // Tambien puede convertirlo a un objeto JSON e igualmente hacerle un echo

     echo "Respuesta";
     //Ceder el control para evitar que hallan mas salidas de datos.
     return;
}
```

Te recuerdo que las salidas que se hagan antes de las cabeceras HTML pueden generar resultados erroneos o lo que es lo mismo, inesperados. Por eso te recomiendo poner esta funcion antes de cualquier codigo HTML y que entregue el control luego de ser procesada usando RETURN;

Luego desde JS en el navegador utilizas la propiedad **responseText** para obtener la salida que dio el servidor.
Aqui tienes info sobre como usarla.
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_httprequest.asp

De esa forma obtienes la salida, pero para agregarla en un contenedor HTML, puedes hacer varias cosas, entre ellas, otorgarle un id a un div y una vez obtenida la respuesta del servidor, obtienes el id del div con **getElementById** donde va a salir la respuesta y usas la propiedad del nodo llamada innerHTML y le asignas **responseText**

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo sencillo usando tus datos con una variable $nums = "2,4,6,8";
Obtienes desde index.php los datos que hay en prueba_numeros.php que seria los id que enviaste.

***index.php***

```
<button onclick = "ObtenerNumeros();">Solicitar Numeros</button>

<div id = "nums"></div>

<script>
    function ObtenerNumeros()
    {
        var xhttp;

      if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
         xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      else
         xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
        {
            var elm = document.getElementById("nums").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      } 

      xhttp.open("POST", "prueba_numeros.php");
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.send("numeros=pares");
    }
</script>
```

***prueba_numeros.php***

```
$nums = "2,4,6,8";
if(isset($_POST["numeros"]) && $_POST["numeros"] == "pares")
{
    echo $nums;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En Base a la respuesta de [David Figueras Tamate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/153410/david-figueras-tamame)

he probado su trozo de código en conjunto con dos listas dependientes y me ocurre que se muestra el resultado pero a los pocos segundos se omite

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#anno').on('change', function(){
                if($('#anno').val() == ""){
                    $('#marca').empty();
                    $('<option value = "">Selecciona Marca</option>').appendTo('#marca');
                    $('#marca').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }else{
                    $('#marca').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    //$('#municipio').load('municipio_get.php?id_deparatamento=' + $('#id_deparatamento').val());
                    $('#marca').load('intermedio.php?anno=' + $('#anno').val());
                }
        });
        $('#marca').on('change', function(){
                 
                if($('#marca').val() == ""){
                    $('#modelo').empty();
                    $('<option value = "">Selecciona modelo</option>').appendTo('#modelo');
                    $('#modelo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }else{
                    $('#modelo').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    //alert('intermedio.php?anno=' + $('#anno').val()+'&marca='+ $('#marca').val());
                    //$('#municipio').load('municipio_get.php?id_deparatamento=' + $('#id_deparatamento').val());
                    $('#modelo').load('intermedio.php?anno=' + $('#anno').val()+'&marca='+ $('#marca').val());
                }
        });
        $('#modelo').on('change', function(){
                 
                 if($('#modelo').val() == ""){
                     $('#motor').empty();
                     $('<option value = "">Selecciona modelo</option>').appendTo('#motor');
                     $('#motor').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                 }else{
                     $('#motor').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
                     //alert('intermedio.php?anno=' + $('#anno').val()+'&marca='+ $('#marca').val()+'&modelo='+ $('#modelo').val());
                     //$('#municipio').load('municipio_get.php?id_deparatamento=' + $('#id_deparatamento').val());
                     $('#motor').load('intermedio.php?anno=' + $('#anno').val()+'&marca='+ $('#marca').val()+'&modelo='+ $('#modelo').val());
                 }
         });
    });
    function cargaBusqueda(){
        var xhttp;

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
            {
                var elm = document.getElementById("nums").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        } 

        xhttp.open("POST", "intermedio.php");
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send('buscar=s&motor=' + $('#motor').val()+ 'y search='+$('#search').val());
        //alert('buscar=s&motor=' + $('#motor').val()+ 'y search='+$('#search').val());
    
    }  
</script>
```

```html
<body>
    <div class = "container-fluid"> 
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
            <div class = "col-md-6 well">
                <h4 class = "text-primary">Busqueda</h4>
                <hr style = "border-top: 1px dotted #8c8b8b;"/>
                    <form class = "form-inline">
                        <div class  =  "form-group">
                            <label>Busqueda:</label>
                            <input type="text" id = "search" class = "form-control" name = "search" required = "required">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="enviar" value="enviar" onclick="cargaBusqueda()"> 
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class  =  "form-group">
                            <label>Año:</label>
                            <select id = "anno" class = "form-control" name = "anno" required = "required">
                                <option value = "">Selecciona un Año</option>
                                <?php
                                        $g_result = getYMMA();
                                    foreach ($g_result as $result){
                                ?>
                                    <option value = "<?php echo $result['anno']?>"><?php echo utf8_encode($result['anno'])?></option>
                                <?php
                                        }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>  
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label>marca:</label>
                            <select  id = "marca" name = "marca"  class = "form-control" disabled = "disabled" required = "required">
                                <option value = "">Selecciona Marca</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label>Modelo:</label>
                            <select  id = "modelo" name = "modelo"  class = "form-control" disabled = "disabled" required = "required">
                                <option value = "">Selecciona Modelo</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label>Motor:</label>
                            <select  id = "motor" name = "motor"  class = "form-control" disabled = "disabled" required = "required">
                                <option value = "">Selecciona motor</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div id="nums">

    </div>
</body>
```

y el código de ejecución es un echo

```php
    if (isset($_POST['buscar']) and ($_POST['buscar']=='s')){
        echo "hola";
        return;
    }
```

el "hola" se muestra pero a los segundos todo se borra

Comment: evita retornar en php null declara un tipo o retorna un void...